# Windows 10 preventing me from loading Ubuntu (from *.ISO file)

Tags: windows-10, iso

Windows 10 is preventing me from loading Ubuntu 20.04 (from an iso-file) parallel to it (Windows). Am I doing something wrong or has Windows found a way of preventing one from doing this?
Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: Exactly how are you using the .iso ?

Comment: Can you tell us what you are doing?

Comment: It's very unclear what problem you are encountering with Windows. Please edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: You need to extract the ISO file to a FAT32 USB disk to make it bootable. Just putting the ISO on the disk without a bootloader will not work. I prefer 7Zip for extracting ISO's

Comment: Here is a list of reasons your USB may not be booting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot

Comment: Thanks C.S. Cameron - this solved the problem. Sorry for being such a noob!

Answer (score 1):

C.S. Cameron's answer applied. My apologies to the rest if I did not frame the question well - so many variables I did not know how to pose the question without getting into unnecessary detail. I was rather hoping for what happened - that someone would recognise a simple solution.
Thanks everyone.
D

Comment: Thank you for taking time to let us know what worked.

Comment: Thank YOU!  "Thumbs up" (can't find gif)